NET Maui - How do I run a SQLight query with parms and populate a List of objects?
I am using SQLight from these packages. SQLite-net-pcl - 1.9.172 SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green - 2.1.8
I have the following working:
SQLiteConnection Database = new SQLiteConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);

public class Location
{
    public string LocationID { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}
List<Location> Locations    = new List<Location>();

String loc = "1290";
Locations = Database.Query<Location>("Select * from Location where LocationID = "+loc).ToList();

// Event is a Picker
Event.ItemsSource = Locations;
Event.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("LocationName");

How do I handle SQL parms in Maui instead of "Select * from Location where LocationID = "+loc

Use LINQ
Locations = Database.Table<Location>().Where(l => l.LocationID == loc).ToList();


'In the database both of these are varchar
LocationID
LocationName
This returns one record with both of those varchar fields.
SELECT * FROM [Location] Where LocationID = 1294
This gives me these errors on build.
string loc = "1294";
Locations = Database.Table().Where(l => l.LocationID = loc).ToList();
CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'
CS1662 Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
'

use == for equality, that was a typo in my original answer

I was going to ask about that single = when I first read this! It works. Great, thank you!
